# How to use gatsby background image plugin

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm new to gatsby and i'm trying to use gatsby background image plugin but it does not work, the image wont show on screen.

Here's my code :

```
import * as React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image'


const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
body{
    background-color: #270A63;
    margin : 0px;
   display:flex;
   
    
}`


const Layout = (props, { children }) => {

  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        bgImage : file(relativePath: {eq: "background.png"}) {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(quality: 90)
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const imageData = data.bgImage.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <BackgroundImage

        Tag="section"
        image={imageData}
        
      >
      </BackgroundImage>

    </React.Fragment>

  )
 
}

export default Layout
```

Layout is a custom component that I'm using in index page.
I used console.log to check imageData and it is an object that looks like this :

```
{bgImage:
childImageSharp:
gatsbyImageData:
backgroundColor: "#680818"
height: 1117
images:
fallback: {src: '/static/32d467ee3060062ab794e34f2002c807/f89cf/background.png', srcSet: '/static/32d467ee3060062ab794e34f2002c807/5829e/bac…60062ab794e34f2002c807/f89cf/background.png 1010w', sizes: '(min-width: 1010px) 1010px, 100vw'}
sources: [{…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object
layout: "constrained"
width: 1010}
```

I don't understand why it does not work.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your GraphQL, you are using a Gatsby version greater or equal than 3. I think your snippet should look like something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import { getImage, GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

import { convertToBgImage } from "gbimage-bridge"
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image'

const GbiBridged = () => {
  const { bgImage }= useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        bgImage : file(relativePath: {eq: "background.png"}) {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(quality: 90)
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  const image = getImage(bgImage)
  const backgroundImage= convertToBgImage(image)

  return (
   <React.Fragment>
     <GlobalStyle />
       <BackgroundImage
         Tag="section"
         {...backgroundImage}
         preserveStackingContext
       >
         <div style={{minHeight: 1000, minWidth: 1000}}>
           <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={"testimage"}/>
         </div>
       </BackgroundImage>
   </React.Fragment>
  )
}
export default GbiBridged
```

*Modified from: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-background-image/#gatsby-34--gatsby-plugin-image applying your code*

Gatsby changed the image plugin from [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) (Gatsby 1 and 2) to [gatsby-plugin-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image) (version 3 onwards). Among other things, it has changed the internal GraphQL nodes of the image data, hence the workaround of using `gatsby-background-image` has also changed accordingly. In your case, you are using the deprecated version of `gatsby-image` so your code is not able to display the image.

You can follow the full discussion in this GitHub thread: https://github.com/timhagn/gatsby-background-image/issues/141

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using any external plugins for this but using CSS to achieve this. This way you don't have to learn any new third-party plugins and can use the knowledge you have about CSS. Here's an example from the docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/using-gatsby-plugin-image/#background-images

```
import * as React from "react"
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

export function Hero() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "grid" }}>
      {/* You can use a GatsbyImage component if the image is dynamic */}
      <StaticImage
        style={{
          gridArea: "1/1",
          // You can set a maximum height for the image, if you wish.
          // maxHeight: 600,
        }}
        layout="fullWidth"
        // You can optionally force an aspect ratio for the generated image
        aspectRatio={3 / 1}
        // This is a presentational image, so the alt should be an empty string
        alt=""
        // Assisi, Perúgia, Itália by Bernardo Ferrari, via Unsplash
        src={
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604975999044-188783d54fb3?w=2589"
        }
        formats={["auto", "webp", "avif"]}
      />
      <div
        style={{
          // By using the same grid area for both, they are stacked on top of each other
          gridArea: "1/1",
          position: "relative",
          // This centers the other elements inside the hero component
          placeItems: "center",
          display: "grid",
        }}
      >
        {/* Any content here will be centered in the component */}
        <h1>Hero text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Accidentally downvoted and try to fix and upvote instead, but StackOverflow is disallowing for some reason